# Custom Web2Lead on CMS Website

Tags: integration, web2lead, website-integration

We have a CMS Website using Squarespace, i want to create multiple step web2lead form. for example i have 2 step form for generate the leads

- the first step will gather leads name,phone,email,etc
- the second step will gather their sensitive information

**but i want to make it 2 transaction process**, first step will be **insert** the lead information first, and the second one will be **update** based on lead id on the first step.

i never no idea the workaround to achieve this, many custom web2lead using PHP when i google it but my website not php based.

Can anyone help me? i really appreciate

Regards,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

Unless Squarespace has some programming interface, I think best option here would be embedding your custom Community page inside iFrame.

This way you wouldn't need to care about integration and just focus on building form inside Salesforce. You might even get away with using some third party package from AppExchange.

You also could create [custom public API](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html), use JSONP (as Salesforce custom REST classes do not support CORS), to communicate from your custom HTML form on Squarespace. Upon lead insert, your class would generate one-time-use token that you'd validate upon second request to update user information. It would probably be good idea to think about DOS protection using platform cache.